# File Decryption in (AESMode.ctr) mode showing Exception Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8' in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, aes

While decoding the video file using `aes-ctr` mode am getting error like below,

`Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'`

Used ffmpeg for encrypting file:

`ffmpeg -i samplevideo.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 enc_v1_file.mp4`

Used Dart to decode video file:

```
Future<String> decryptFile(filePath) async {
    // filePath - Local encrypted file path
    var encodedKey = 'NzZhNmM2NWM1ZWE3NjIwNDZiZDc0OWEyZTYzMmNjYmI=';
    var encodedIv = 'YTdlNjFjMzczZTIxOTAzM2MyMTA5MWZhNjA3YmYzYjg=';
    var encryptedBase64EncodedString = new File(filePath).readAsStringSync();
    var decoded = base64.decode(encryptedBase64EncodedString); // Error in this line
    final key1 = enc.Key.fromBase64(encodedKey);
    final iv = enc.IV.fromBase64(encodedIv);
    final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key1, mode: enc.AESMode.ctr));
    final decrypted = encrypter.decryptBytes(enc.Encrypted(decoded), iv: iv);
    final filename = '${p.basenameWithoutExtension(filePath)}.mp4';
    final directoryName = p.dirname(filePath);
    final newFilePath = p.join(directoryName, filename);
    var newFile = new File(newFilePath);
    await newFile.writeAsBytes(decrypted);
    return newFilePath;
}
```

Comment: First, you're trying to read a binary file in text mode, then you assume the content is Base64 (it is not) so this is bound to fail. Second, what are you trying to do? CENC uses sample encryption, it doesn't encrypt the whole file.